# jq produces memory overflow

Tags: json, out-of-memory, jq

I have a json file where a time series in stored under `data` key and and an object id is in `info` key:

```
{info:
  {id: abc},
data:[
   [10, 5, 3],
   [12, 6, 4],
   # 5000 list items
   ]
}
```

I would like to flatten the json and produce something similar to:

```
[
{id: abc, time: 10, x: 5, y: 3},
{id: abc, time: 12, x: 6, y: 4},
# the rest of 5000 points
]
```

I'm running a jq query and seems to work well to produce a series of items:

`"{time: .data[][0], x: .data[][2], y: .data[][1], item: .info.id}"`

When I try to put the same expression into a list to create a list of dicts, I'm hitting a memory overflow limit:

`"[{time: .data[][0], x: .data[][2], y: .data[][1], item: .info.id}]"`

Is there anyhting else I can do differently? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you're probably running into a combinatorial explosion problem.  If .data has N (top level) items, then your expression with three occurrences of .data[] will require N^3 iterations to construct and will be correspondingly large.  The large number of iterations is not the problem -- it's keeping all the constructed items in memory at the same time that is most probably the problem.  If you explained what you're really trying to do, we might be able to help.

Comment: @peak - thank you for the comment, I did not realize I might be getting the N^3 combinations, I was expecting just N items. I updated the question to show the original intent of the data transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@peak has already pointed out the problem with your query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60463005/jq-produces-memory-overflow/60463974#comment106963762_60463005), and here is the solution based on the insight he provided:

```
[ (.data[] | {time: .[0], x: .[1], y: .[2]}) + {id: .info.id} ]
```

[See it online on jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/23F00IzD38)